# How to split a string based on space and a limit?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For eg, I have a string:

```
var s = "Tyrannosaurus Rex";
```

My limit is 4. So I want to split this string to 4 letter short strings into an array. Which can be done using:

```
var arr = s.match(/.{1,4}/g);
```

But the troubling thing is, it should consider space or \n as a splitting criteria as well. So that final output should be:

```
["Tyra", "nnos", "auru", "s", "Rex"]
```

and not this:

```
["Tyra", "nnos", "auru", "s Re", "x"]
```

Any clean solution would be helpful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply modify your regex to not match spaces or new lines:

```js
var s = "Tyrannosaurus Rex";
console.log(s.match(/[^ \n]{1,4}/g));
```

Comment: Awesome! Regex to the rescue as always!

Answer (score 0):

Use this `/\S{1,4}/g`. It will consider every character except space, tabs and newline.

```js
var s = "Tyrannosaurus Rex";
console.log(s.match(/\S{1,4}/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by splitting it into words then applying your regexp:

```js
var s = "Tyrannosaurus Rex";
var words = s.split(' ');

var arr = [].concat(...words.map(w => w.match(/.{1,4}/g)));

console.log(arr);
```

EDIT: Leaving this here but @le_m answer is provably better